# Aura handle change not capturing old values correctly

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, aura

I have a component that tracks an aura handler:

```
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.objList}" action="{!c.handleValueChange}"/>
<aura:attribute name="objList" type="List" />
```

but for some reason, if I change an attribute on any of the values, it displays the new value even if I'm trying to display the old value on the handler:

```
    let newValues = event.getParam("value");
    let oldValues = event.getParam("oldValue")
    console.log(oldValues); //If an object value on the list, for example Obj.Number was 1, and it changed to 2, this displays it as 2.
    console.log(newValues); //this displays the object number value on the list as 2, as expected.
```

Is there somethiing that I'm missing?

Comment: What is objList?

Comment: @sfdcfox objList is a List of objects, for example: [{"Id":"01t0H000009qincQAA", "Number": "2"}]

Comment: The docs suggest it should work, but I'm seeing the same behavior as you. I don't think it should be considered reliable.

Comment: I see, do you know if there's a workaround for the oldvalue? I do need to use the handler for the new value, which works as expected, but I do need to make some validations with the old value.

Comment: Just store the old data somewhere so you can reference it. Instead of `aura:valueChange`, consider just using an old-fashioned `onchange` handler so you can identify which data is changing and how.